module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'dot'
I tried to use crf layer on colab
Replace K.dot with tf.matmul in the crf.py file within the keras_contrib library
To this:
input_energy = self.activation(tf.matmul(X, self.kernel) + self.bias) 

additional
pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed, Dense, Dropout
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF 
import tensorflow as tf  # Import TensorFlow


What exactly is your problem, can you elaborate more on that? Some information.tensorflow.keras.backend.dot is deprecated likewise is keras_contrib. You should check out Tensorflow Addons instead. from tensorflow_addons.layers.crf import CRF

I have successfully executed the code in TensorFlow 2.17.1 .Please refer
gist with the code is attached for your reference.Let me know if you are still
facing the issue
